# error on sharepoint farm configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error, server-farm, farm-setup

I am new in sharepoint platform ,face problem on farm configuration.

Failed to product configuration on sharepoint 2013 .Want to create a new server farm.After given necessary information on configuration wizard I face bellow error .
[image]

My sql server version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
    Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

What is the problem is ? How to solve this configuration problem?need help on this issues.

If have any query plz ask,any type of suggestion will be acceptable.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL Server is unsupported, SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported with SharePoint 2013.

You need 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 min to configure the SharePoint. Check Software requirement from this technet. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.15).aspx#section4